# MediaPlayer continues playing after Activity.recreate()

Tags: android, themes, android-mediaplayer

I work on a mediaplayer app with different themes.
After changing themes in the SettingsActivity I recreate Settings- and MainActivity that the new theme will be shown.

```
MainActivity.getInstance().recreate();
SettingsActivity.getInstance().recreate();
```

After this recreation, my mediaplayer App continues playing.

```
getTransportControls().pause();
```

doesn't work.

Pause mediaplayer befor the activities are recreated, then

```
getTransportControls().pause();
```

works but that's not I want the player to do.

My MediaBrowserService is following this example. 
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/background-audio-in-android-with-mediasessioncompat--cms-27030
There is no bind between Service and mediaplayer.

**1. Question:** How can I continue playing after recreation?

**2. Question:** How can I start mediaplayer after recreation - when it was privously stopped before Activity recreation?

Can anyone help me with my problems.

Thanks
GGK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the `onDestroy()` method, I had to generate a new `Intent` then stop the service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AudioService.class);
stopService(intent);
```